# Retrieve column value in DevExpress GridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Can I ask that is there anyway to get the value of certain column in aspxGridView ? 
For example, there is 3 columns (ID, Name, Age) in aspxGridView, after retrieve data from database, there is only 1 row of data, is there anyway for me to get the value of "Age" column in that aspxGridView?

Comment: int v = Convert.ToInt32(aspxGridView.GetRowValues(0, "Age")); I found solution already, thanks